# Simple python cicle not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to input several numbers and getting an output with the total sum and the counter for how many inputs until the input is the string "." but it just keeps adding the first input over and over again. What am I doing wrong?

```
sum = 0
counter = 0
x = float(input())
while x!=".":
    sum = sum + x
    counter += 1
print ("sum:",sum)
print ("counter:",counter)
```

Comment: Run input inside while

Comment: Also you have to use try-except around float(input()) because you will get value error when you input a string. You need to handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean to get new input every iteration, and break the loop when the input is `".'` Here is what you should do:

```
sum,counter=0,0 #set numeric variables
done=False #create a Boolean to control the loop
while not done:
    x=input()
    if x==".":
        done=True # break the loop if x is "."
    else:
        sum+=float(x)
        counter+=1
print ("Sum:",sum)
print ("Counter:",counter)
```

Comment: The output of `input` is *guaranteed* to be a `str` in Python 3; no need to check its type (which is more idiomatically done with `isinstance`, not type-object comparison, to accommodate subclassing).

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `input` *in* the loop, not just *before* the loop. You also have to check that its value isn't `.` before you attempt to convert it into a floating-point number.

```
x = input()
while x != '.':
    try:
        x = float(x)
    except ValueError:
        print("{} not a floating point number, ignoring".format(x))
    else:
        sum = sum + x
        counter += 1
    x = input()
print ("sum:", sum)
print ("counter:", counter)
```

To avoid calling `input` in two separate places, you can make your loop "infinite" with an explicit `if` to check the current input:

```
while True:
    x = input()
    if x == ".":
        break
    try:
        x = float(x)
    except ValueError:
        print("{} not a floating point number, ignoring".format(x))
    else:
        sum = sum + x
        counter += 1
print ("sum:", sum)
print ("counter:", counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do:

```
float()
```

of:

```
"."
```

This function only accepts numbers.

Also you need to do:

```
input()
```

into a loop